# How many connected graphs with $n$ nodes are there approximately?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

OEIS states the the number of graphs with $0,1,2,...,19$ nodes is
 $$1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 21, 112, 853, 11117, 261080, 11716571, 1006700565, 164059830476,$$
 $$50335907869219, 29003487462848061, 31397381142761241960, 63969560113225176176277,$$
 $$245871831682084026519528568, 1787331725248899088890200576580,$$ 
 $$24636021429399867655322650759681644$$

- Is there a good approximation formula, in particular for large numbers ?

Comment: Most graphs with $n$ nodes are connected, aren't they? So, as a *very* rough approximation, all of them?

Comment: The probability of a random graph being disconnected or having a nontrivial automorphism is very small for large $n$, so a good approximation is just $2^{n(n-1)/2}/n!$.  For $n=19$, this differs from the true number of connected graphs by about $0.1$%.

Comment: @mjqx this answer is exactly what I wanted. For $n = 75$, the accuracy is overhelming. Formulate it as an answer, and I will upvote and accept it. I thought about this approximation, but I am very astonished how accurate it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of a random graph being disconnected or having a nontrivial automorphism is very small for large $n$, so a good approximation is just $$\frac{2^{n(n−1)/2}}{n!}...$$that is, the number of graphs on $n$ labeled nodes, divided by the maximum number of inequivalent permutations of the labels.  Note that there are two approximations being made, which partially cancel each other out: taking symmetries into account increases this number, and removing disconnected graphs decreases it.

For $n=19$, this differs from the true number of connected graphs by about $0.1\%$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you looked at [A001349](https://oeis.org/A001349), presumably you saw this in the Formula section:

> For asymptotics see Lupanov 1959, 1960, also Turner and Kautz, p. 18. - N. J. A. Sloane, Apr 08 2014

Have you followed up those references?

Comment: I must admit, no. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: The OEIS link has a typo in the label, should I correct it?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that.  I edited.